# Math puzzle - Running Out of Digits

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

You initially have 100 of each digit from 0 to 9. This means you have 1000 digits
in total. This count for each digit is shown in the table below.

| Digit | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # Remaining | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |

Now start counting by ones, from 1. Each time you say a number you must
remove the digits required to make the number from your stockpile of digits.
For example, after you have counted from 1 to 13, the above table now looks like:

| Digit | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # Remaining | 99 | 94 | 98 | 98 | 99 | 99 | 99 | 99 | 99 | 99 |

What is the largest number you can count to without running out of the digits
needed to form the number?

Comment: Hi. You should probably clarify whether you have to use all of the numbers from 1 to the limit, or if numbers can be skipped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can count to:

> 162

Because:

> It's quite obvious that the `1` will be the most used digit, since it's the lowest non-zero digit. Now, there are twelve `1` from 1-20. After that, it's an additional one `1` per ten, up til 99, making it 20. Now, we continue adding `1` every count, in addition to the extra ones in `101, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161`, a and `110-119`.

It's basically:

> `21 + 9` for 1...99, then we add +1 for numbers 100...199, +1 for every tenth, 101, 111, 121, 131, ..., as well as the extra 9 ones for `110-119`.

Check the [edit history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/93701/2) (it took too much vertical space) for an exhaustive demonstration (credit to @Avi):

Comment: Beat me to it by four minutes - good work!

Comment: Pipped me by ~ 10 seconds :x

Answer (score 5):

My calculations are a little rushed, but I think the answer is:

> 162

Working:

> The dominant factor is going to be 1s - in particular we use one for every number from 100 to 199, so we can't possibly reach 200. We use at least one 1 for every other digit we count, since 1 always comes up first.
> I homed in by trial and error, but the trick I used was calculating each place separately:
> In the hundreds place, we use 63 copies of 1, for the numbers 100 to 162.
> In the tens place, we use 20 - 10 to 19 and 110 to 119 (we've already counted the 100s places).
> In the ones place, we use one in each ten numbers, for 17 total - (0)1, 11, 21, 31, ... 161

If I haven't made an arithmetic error (like the one I caught while typing!) that gives us our answer

Comment: Pipped by four minutes!

Answer (score 3):

Same answer

> 162

as the preceding ones, but this is by a quick Perl 5 one-liner I threw together.

> `perl -E"@a=(100)x10;L:say++$i;$a[$_]--for($i=~/./g);goto L unless grep{$_<=0}@a"`