# Running Out of Digits, Level 3

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

<sub>[The challenge idea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/93700/31824) is credited to [HelloWorld1337](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/65588/HelloWorld1337).</sub>

---

You initially have x of each digit from 0 to 9. This means you have x * 10 digits in total. This count for each digit is shown in the table below.

| Digit | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # Remaining | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |

Now start counting by ones, from 1. Each time you say a number you must remove the digits required to make the number from your stockpile of digits. For example, after you have counted from 1 to 13, the above table now looks like:

As an example, if you counted from 1 to 13 and didn't skip any numbers, the above table will look like:

| Digit | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # Remaining | x-1 | x-6 | x-2 | x-2 | x-1 | x-1 | x-1 | x-1 | x-1 | x-1 |

What is the largest number x you can count to without running out of the digits needed to form the number?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! It seems you have two definitions of x as a variable - lowercase "x" for the number of digits left, and uppercase "X" for the largest number created. I'd suggested changing one of those to a different letter to avoid confusion.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you.  My intent is for those to be the same number; I've edited them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> 199,981.  Mmm. Not this. You can add more and still work: 199,990

Details:

> Short answer: I wrote a script. I know, I know.
>  Roughly, though, 1 in 10 of each digit is a 1. Consider 199,990. Take the last 5 digits of 199,990 and it gives you ~99,995 ones. To this add the 99,990 ones for the hundred-thousands place and you get ~199,985.
>  At this value, each additional number is adding 1 additional 1 (in the hundred-thousands place), so you can increase/decrease until you get a second 1 somewhere else. So this suggests that for $x\in [199,981;199,990]$ you use exactly $x$ 1s to write out the numbers from 1 to $x$.
>  When you go to 199,980 you will have 1 one left over. When you get to 199,991, you will be 1 one short.

---

Edit: Paul Panzer is correct. He should get the tick. Here's a justification:

> If $x = k\times10^n-1$ then the number of ones needed is $kn10^{n-1}$ plus an additional $10^n$ if $k\geq2$.
>  This can be used to show that $1\times10^9<x<2\times10^9$.
>  With a bit of care, you can now add $2\times10^8$ and discover that $x$ is less than that. But you can add $1\times10^8$, so $x>1.1\times10^9$.
>  Continue with that process and you get 1,111,111,110 as the maximum $x$

Comment: Scripts are good!  Long time lurker--always appreciate what the programming gang here comes up with to solve these kids of questions. I kind of figured someone would either have a script or some simple-but-elegant proof of why it is what it is.

Comment: I think if Paul Panzer's answer is correct, then it's clearly a larger number than mine. I haven't checked it, but it looks good.

Comment: As per 00Average comments under his answer, seems like yours is correct, and Paul's answer corroborates your answer (visually).

Comment: I've been second-guessing myself, but you both show that your answer is correct.  At each new order of magnitude, the count equalizes at all nines (evident on Paul's plot at each 10^n), but then each time we add a digit, the total count of digits is front-loaded with ones, (also visible in his diagram) increasing faster than y=x.  It's this front-loading that stops the count before we reach 1,111,111,110.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's:

> 1,111,111,110

No proof, though, but a few remarks and a suggestive plot:

> the number of ones will never be smaller than that of any other digit
>  
>  for x of the form 99...99 (k digits) the distribution of 1,2,3,... is even each having been used exactly k x 10^{k-1} times; zeros will have occurred 11...12 (k digits) times less often.
>  
>  for x of the form 11...10 (k digits) the number of ones used is k x 11...11 (k-1 digits)
>  
>  [image]

Comment: It looks like your plot validates Dr. X's answer, unless I'm missing something...  Isn't the 1's count kissing (and ostensibly crossing) the line of y=x/total#ofdigits=number right around 200,000?  It feels like this plot answered the question too, and I just needed to phrase it better.